# Dex2jar generating empty converted jar files

Tags: android, apk, dex2jar

I tried converting my apk file from apk to a jar file.

Steps:

1- Copy apk to my dex2jar folder

2- Drag and release apk onto dex2jar.bat

3- apk_dex2jar.jar is created

4- Open apk_dex2jar.jar in JD Gui

5- Empty screen for JD Gui

Can someone please advise what I have done wrong?

I have also tried doing step 4 using the terminal, but it yields the same result. I am running on Windows 11.

Comment: Why do you decompile your own APK? Dex2jar is not the only decompiler (and there are multiple forks of dex2jar). You can try e.g. JadX-Gui.